# how to indent for tab space after writing a statement

Tags: xtext, xtend

How to get a tab space for beautification after writing a statement in Xtext.
   Here is my code is in Xtext grammar :

```
 Block:
      '_block' 
         name=ID
     '_endblock' 
    ;
```

and UI template is

```
override complete_BLOCK(EObject model, RuleCall ruleCall, ContentAssistContext context, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
      super.complete_BLOCK(model, ruleCall, context, acceptor)
      acceptor.accept(createCompletionProposal("_block \n    
    _endblock","_block",null,context));

}
```

How do I indent for a tab space after writing a block statement?

Comment: is this about content assist, about auto edit, or about formatters

Comment: i have xtext parser rule like this                                                              
  Block:   '_block' name=ID '_endblock' ;  for this i have written a template in class MydslProposalProvider extends AbstractMagikProposalProvider { override complete_BLOCK(EObject model, RuleCall ruleCall, ContentAssistContext context, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
  super.complete_BLOCK(model, ruleCall, context, acceptor)
  acceptor.accept(createCompletionProposal("_block \n    
_endblock","_block",null,context));}

Comment: i have formatter  like this def dispatch void format(BLOCK block, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
  val ds =block.blbody
     block.allRegionsFor.keywords(",").forEach[append[oneSpace; autowrap]]
      block.allRegionsFor.keyword("_block").append[newLine].surround[newLine]
       block.allRegionsFor.keyword("_endblock").prepend[newLine]
          interior(
      block.regionFor.keyword("_block").append[newLine].surround[newLine] , 
        block.regionFor.keyword("_endblock").prepend[newLine]
         )[indent]
           block.blbody.forEach[format]

Comment: no what is your question about. formatting, content assist and auto edit are 3 different things

Comment: it is working with indentation when i hit formatter through format option but i need when i click my template and i hit enter directly i need a tab space like class A { } gives a tab space in java

Comment: this feature is called autoedit and you need to implement a customization of DefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider

Comment: hi christian,i am asking about formatting

Comment: if you want to format you have to call the formatter ?!?

Comment: can you please share the steps to do that

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

to implement a formatter

1. open the mwe2 file
2. add `formatter = {generateStub = true}` to the `language = StandardLanguage {` section of the workflow
3. regenerate the language
4. open the `MyDslFormatter` Xtend class and implement it

to call the formatter

1. mark the section to format or dont mark to format everything
2. call rightclick -> Source -> Format or the Shortcut Cmd/Crtl + Shift + F

here is a very naive no failsafe impl of an auto edit strategy

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl1.ui;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.DocumentCommand;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IAutoEditStrategy;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IRegion;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.autoedit.DefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Provider;

public class YourAutoEditStrategyProvider extends DefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider {

    public static class BlockStrategy implements IAutoEditStrategy {

        private static final String BLOCK =  "_block";

        protected int findEndOfWhiteSpace(IDocument document, int offset, int end) throws BadLocationException {
            while (offset < end) {
                char c= document.getChar(offset);
                if (c != ' ' && c != '\t') {
                    return offset;
                }
                offset++;
            }
            return end;
        }

        @Override
        public void customizeDocumentCommand(IDocument d, DocumentCommand c) {
            if ("\n".equals(c.text)) {
                if (d.getLength()> BLOCK.length()) {
                    try {
                        if ((BLOCK+" ").equals(d.get(c.offset-BLOCK.length()-1, BLOCK.length()+1)) || (BLOCK).equals(d.get(c.offset-BLOCK.length(), BLOCK.length()))) {
                            int p= (c.offset == d.getLength() ? c.offset  - 1 : c.offset);
                            IRegion info= d.getLineInformationOfOffset(p);
                            int start= info.getOffset();

                            // find white spaces
                            int end= findEndOfWhiteSpace(d, start, c.offset);
                            int l = 0;
                            StringBuilder buf= new StringBuilder(c.text);
                            if (end > start) {
                                // append to input
                                buf.append(d.get(start, end - start));
                                l += (end - start);
                            }

                            buf.append("\t");
                            buf.append("\n");
                            buf.append(d.get(start, end - start));

                            c.text= buf.toString();
                            c.caretOffset = c.offset+2+l;
                            c.shiftsCaret=false;
                        }
                    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Inject
    private Provider<BlockStrategy> blockStrategy;

    @Override
    protected void configure(IEditStrategyAcceptor acceptor) {
        super.configure(acceptor);
        acceptor.accept(blockStrategy.get(), IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
    }

}
```

and dont forget to bind

```
class MyDslUiModule extends AbstractMyDslUiModule {

    override bindAbstractEditStrategyProvider() {
        YourAutoEditStrategyProvider
    }

}
```

Comment: thnx christian, i did the above procedure for formatting and it is working fine in my window, i have a question like can we do auto formatting like it should append a tab space when we entering into a new line like java class do

Comment: as i said: no. the only thing you can do is autoedit. gave you the pointers to look for

Comment: btw this is configured out of the box so if you type enter between the brackets in `class xxx {}` you get the cursor indented after the newline

Comment: you dont add it there. you simply add a binding. please read the docs on DI https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/302_configuration.html#dependency-injection